# How can i get the #addin preprosessor directive to install to custom folder

Tags: cakebuild

I'm running a docker container where I map the source code folder from the local filesystem to the /src folder

When I then run the "dotnet cake" script, this installs a nuget package for npm with

`#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Npm&version=2.0.0`

This then installs the package in the /src/tools/Addin folder.

Is there any way for me to get it to install this to another folder? F.eks the /home/ folder

Answer (score 3):

Cake has multiple [configuration options](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/configuration/). The option you are looking for is the [addins path](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/configuration/default-configuration-values#addins-path).

If you want to configure Cake using a [configuration file](https://cakebuild.net/docs/running-builds/configuration/set-configuration-values#configuration-file), you would create a `cake.config` file, containing:

```ini
[Paths]
Addins=/home/
```

Keep in mind, though that this will change the installation path for all the addins in your Cake file!

Comment: Environment variable was the way to go for me, setting it when I build the base docker image, I just needed the following line in the DOCKERFILE :  ENV CAKE_PATHS_ADDINS=/home/user/